# Jest Test Visual Studio Code Debugger Throws "Error No Such a File" Exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use Jest with Visual Studio Code with debugger. My launch file is:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug CRA Tests",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts",
      "args": ["test", "--runInBand", "--no-cache", "--env=jsdom"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I start runner, it throws that exception:

> Exception has occurred: Error Error: ENOENT: no such file or
>   directory, stat '**/*.(ts|tsx)'
>       at Object.statSync (fs.js:932:3)
>       at typeSync (/Users/can/code/new-mail/node_modules/path-type/index.js:27:16)
>       at /Users/can/code/new-mail/node_modules/dir-glob/index.js:46:48
>       at Array.map ()
>       at module.exports.sync (/Users/can/code/new-mail/node_modules/dir-glob/index.js:46:30)
>       at globDirs (/Users/can/code/new-mail/node_modules/globby/index.js:58:9)
>       at getPattern (/Users/can/code/new-mail/node_modules/globby/index.js:61:64)
>       at /Users/can/code/new-mail/node_modules/globby/index.js:107:19
>       at Array.reduce ()
>       at module.exports.sync (/Users/can/code/new-mail/node_modules/globby/index.js:106:26)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the filter selector for breakpoints in VS Code **does not include** `Caught Exceptions`:

[image: VS Code breakpoints selector]

That would make the debugger stop for any exception, even if it's handled properly, and even if it happens in an external package and not in your code.